# How to calculate the volume of a skip bin container knowing the height of the material inside

Tags: geometry, functions, definite-integrals, volume

I need to know hot to calculate the volume of a skip bin (also known as a skip container or dumpster in some areas) with varying length and width.

It seems like a isosceles trapezoid when you look at it from the sides or the front. Like this:

[image: A skip container]

The width of the skip varies only slightly, but the length below and above vary by about a yard.

Or like this:

[image: A skip container]

The point is that in my work we put some semi-solids on it, and we use some aproximation to calculate the volume.
I'd like to know how to calculate the formula for exact value of the volume of liquid (i.e.) inside, but I keep thinking that it has something to do with integrals, infinitesimal sum, or something like it that exceeds my knowledge.

Anyone cares to help me, please?

Comment: Please do not change question. Once you replaced image with another container figure, you invalidated a correct answer by user WHY. In such cases either add another image to the question or post a new question, so that valid answers remain valid and each variant can be adressed separately.

Comment: Additionally, when you replaced the image, your own comment became false: *'The width of the skip varies only slightly, but the length below and above vary by about a yard.'* was true for a yellow container, but is clearly false to a green one.

Comment: Edited to show the previous image, too.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could use integration, but that would be tediously unnecessary.

Thankfully, some simple geometry should suffice once you have some measurements:

1. Find the area of the trapezoid face (left side on your picture) through the following formula:

> [image]

2. Then multiply that area by the "width" of the bin to find the total volume.

Conceptually, you could think of it as stacking up a bunch of those trapezoidal areas.

---

<sup><sub>The picture of the formula is from a Google search for "[area of trapezoid](https://www.google.com/search?q=area%20of%20trapezoid&oq=area%20of%20trapezoid&aqs=chrome..69i57.3376j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)"</sub></sup>

Comment: Actually, no. That's because there are two trapezoids simultaneously: both in the lenght of the skip and in the width.

Comment: I don't think I'm seeing a second trapezoid from the picture you posted. Do you have another picture that could provide some clarification?

Comment: Here you can see the change in width better.

[Another skip bin](http://ezigreenskipbins.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/ezi-skip-bin1.png)

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, their are two pairs of trapezoid faces opposite each other (i.e., in the image of the yellow skip, the left face isn't actually 90 degrees vertical [even thought that's what it looks like], it's leaning to the left a little). In that case, I don't think there's a simple calculation. You'd have to break the whole thing up into simpler shapes and calculate each of the volumes separately.

Comment: I must say though, most of the skips I Googled looked like they have a constant length, which means the above method I posted in my answer would apply to those. You might want to change the picture of the yellow skip for something that looks more like the one you have mind though. Someone might come along with a more detailed answer. Best!

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the image to better picture the change in dimensions.
As you've said, the formula you mentioned is the one we've been using, as a simplification of the real case by assuming the change in width is neglectable.
The simplified formula gets the number done almost right, but I just got curious about how to calculate the volume taking into account both changes. I tried to make some function F(h), but didn't get anywhere.
Let's hope someone can help with this.

Comment: Wrong. That would work if just two faces were trapezoid (probably parallel *), and other two sides were parallelograms (rectangles in case *). But the image shows that all four sides are trapezoids, so the 'width' is different on different heights and the simple prism formula ('base area times height', which you transformed into 'side area times width') does not apply.

Comment: Whoops, apparently the image was changed and the original actually was showing parallel trapezoid sides. In that case your answer was correct.

Answer (score 1):

The skip can be treated as a frustum of a rectangular right pyramid.

Let's say that the open face (larger) has dimensions $a \times b$, the base face (smaller) has dimensions $c \times d$, the skip has a vertical height between the opening and the base of $x$, and it's filled to height $h$ as measured from the base face with some material.

Then, the volume of the entire skip is:

$$V = \frac{xd}{3c}(a^2 + ac + c^2)$$

and the volume of the material is:

$$V_{fill} = \frac{cd}{3}\cdot [(\kappa^2 - 1)\frac{xc}{a-c} + \kappa^2h] $$

where $\displaystyle \kappa = \frac{ha - hc + xc}{xc}$

I'm almost certain the latter formula for the fill volume can be further simplified, but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Let:

> $l$ – length of the base
>   $w$ – width of the base
>   $\Delta l$ – diference between the lengths of the top and the base
>   $\Delta w$ – diference between the widths of the top and the base
>   $H$ – height of the figure

Then the volume:

$$V=\left(lw + \frac{l\Delta w + w\Delta l}2 + \frac {\Delta l\Delta w}3\right)H$$